# how to associate a thread or background process to our activity

Tags: android

i have to display text of the playing audio (file in sdcard). After given audio progress time i have to change the text of my TextView.

For this i think i should make a thread which monitor this stuff and behave like following:

```
if((player.isPlaying) == 0)
{
   get new text and set to textView   
   pick relavent audio and play
}
```

**can we associate a thread or some function like that to our Activity that constantly monitors it**

I am sorry i am new to android please help me with some example or at least idea!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no such thing as "associate a thread with Activity" in Android. If you want to manage thread in parallel with Activity lifecycle - you can do that. You'll need to start when you want it, and stop it in `onDestroy()` (to put it briefly).

Also, in your particular case you do not need to have separate thread that monitors player. You need to set different listeners for you player. Assuming you're using standard Android's `MediaPlayer`, you need to set: [`OnErrorListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnErrorListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener%29) and [`OnCompletionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29).

This will allow you to not waste resources and have precise reaction on player's state changes.

Comment: Thanks pretty much for the suggestion. It helped 100%